# cannot extract text from tag Beautifulsoup

Tags: beautifulsoup, text-extraction

the following command correctly extract a table from a HTML page:

```
[tr.findAll('td') for tr in table.findAll('tr',{'class': "js-file-line"})]


[[<td class="blob-num js-line-number" data-line-number="1" id="L1"></td>],
[<td class="blob-num js-line-number" data-line-number="2" id="L2"></td>,
<td>Arsenal</td>,
<td>38</td>,
<td>26</td>,
<td>9</td>,
<td>3</td>,
<td>79</td>,
<td>36</td>,
<td>87</td>],
[<td class="blob-num js-line-number" data-line-number="3" id="L3"></td>,
<td>Liverpool</td>,
etc.
```

I would like to modify the command to extract the content of each td.
but I cannot extract text from each line since the .text returns an error:
I use the following command:

```
[tr.findAll('td').text[1:] for tr in table.findAll('tr',{'class': "js-file-line"})][1:]
```

Where [1:] are used to skip headers (and they works fine. Tested). The problem is the .text which results the following error:

```
ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. 
You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. 
Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

I am actually using findAll which from my understanding is equivalent to find_All.

Sorry if this is too basic question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `find_All` method returns a `ResultSet` object which is basically a list of `Tag` objects.
`text` is a `Tag` attribute, so you should use one more list comprehension.

```
txt = [
    [td.text for td in tr.find_all('td')][1:] 
    for tr in table.find_all('tr', {'class': "js-file-line"})
    ][1:]
```

Or, if the rows contain only 'td' tags you can use the [`strings`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings) generator.

```
txt = [list(tr.strings)[1:] for tr in table.find_all('tr', {'class': "js-file-line"})][1:]
```

Comment: I need to think about it since a bit mysterious to me but it works great! Thank you.

Comment: Feel free to ask any questions